# links in applications no longer open in browser?

Tags: windows-7

clicking on a link, such as the ones in launchers like WoT's or Starwars the old Republic used to open in Firefox. now, nothing happens. 
the only change was to install a newer version of the AMD CCC and display driver. any program with links that open in a web browser no longer work because clicking the links do not work

Comment: Removing the browser currently configured to open links usually causes this. Start -> Default Programs on the right, Set your default programs. Select the web browser you want to open links in on the left then use the options on the bottom to change to it.

Comment: it's already set, but clicking the links still does nothing. it's not just the wrong browser, it's simply not doing anything at all